# How to get default ZoneOffset in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, timezone, timezone-offset

With Java 8 we know use `ZoneId.default()` can get system default `ZoneId`, but how to get default `ZoneOffset`?

I see that a `ZoneId` has some "rules" and each rule has a `ZoneOffset`, is that means a `ZoneId` may have more than one `ZoneOffset`?

Comment: try `ZoneOffset.systemDefault()`

Comment: Many timezones have different offsets due to daylight savings time.

Comment: `ZoneOffset.systemDefault()` returns a `ZoneId`, though.

Comment: Current ZoneOffset is a function of ZoneId and Instant. `ZoneOffset current = zone.getRules().getOffset(instant)`

Comment: @yanys that instant is from Instant.now()?

Comment: @FredSuvn if you want to know ZoneId for now, than yes, it is.

Comment: @yanys I don't understand why a zoneoffset is influenced by a instant. A zoneoffset is not fixed??

Comment: @FredSuvn I believe yanys is getting at the concept that it makes no sense to ask for an offset without specifying a time zone and a moment (a date-time value). Ex: Daylight Saving Time in `America/Los_Angeles` causes the offset to be `-08:00` currently, but changes to `-07:00` in the summer. So you cannot ask for an offset without saying **when in effect** and for **which time zone**. See [my Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41430483/642706) for more discussion.

Answer (score 299, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.now().getOffset()
```

But you likely should be using a time zone rather than a mere offset-from-UTC.

```
ZoneId.systemDefault()
```

## Offset versus Time Zone

An [offset-from-UTC](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) is merely a number of hour, minutes, and seconds — nothing more. For example, `-08:00` means eight hours behind the UTC, and `+05:45` means five hours and forty-five minutes ahead of [UTC](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

A [time zone](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) is a **history of past, present, and future changes to the offset** used by the people of a particular region. Anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) causing shifts in the offset over specific periods of time are tracked over time, in the past as they happened, and in the future when politicians have announced planned changes.

So **better to use a zone** when known.

The offset for any region varies over time. For example, [DST in the United States](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_in_the_United_States) shifts the offset by an hour for about half the year and then restoring that hour back to the offset during the other half of the year. The entire purpose of a time zone is to document those shifts in offset.

So it really **makes no sense to ask for an offset without a date-time**. In [`America/Los_Angeles`](//time.is/Los_Angeles), for example in part of this year the offset is `-08:00` but in another part of the year it is `-07:00` during DST.

### `OffsetDateTime`

So let's specify a moment as an [`OffsetDateTime`](//docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html), and then extract the [`ZoneOffset`](//docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now ();
ZoneOffset zoneOffset = odt.getOffset ();
```

> odt.toString(): 2017-01-02T15:19:47.162-08:00

> zoneOffset.toString(): -08:00

That `now` method is actually applying implicitly the JVM’s current default time zone. I suggest you always make that explicit by specifying your desired/expected time zone. Even if you want the current default zone, say so explicitly to make your intentions clear. Eliminate the ambiguity about whether you intended the default or failed to consider time zone as so often happens with programmers. Call [`ZoneId.systemDefault`](//docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#systemDefault()).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now ( ZoneId.systemDefault () );
ZoneOffset zoneOffset = odt.getOffset ();
```

> ZoneId.systemDefault().toString(): America/Los_Angeles

> odt: 2017-01-02T15:19:47.162-08:00

> zoneOffsetOfOdt: -08:00

A caution about depending on the default zone: This default can be changed at any moment by any code in any thread within the JVM. If important, ask the user for their intended time zone.

You can ask the offset for its amount of time as a total number of seconds.

```
int offsetSeconds = zoneOffset.getTotalSeconds ();
```

> offsetSeconds: -28800

### `ZonedDateTime`

Another example: Perhaps you want to know what the offset will be on Christmas Day this year in Québec. Specify the time zone `America/Montreal`, get a [`ZonedDateTime`](//docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html), ask for its offset as a `ZoneOffset` object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2017 , 12 , 25 );
ZonedDateTime zdtXmas = ld.atStartOfDay( z );
ZoneOffset zoneOffsetXmas = zdtXmas.getOffset();
```

> zdtXmas.toString(): 2017-12-25T00:00-05:00[America/Montreal]

> zoneOffsetXmas.toString(): -05:00

> zoneOffsetXmas.getTotalSeconds(): -18000

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy.]

### `ZoneId`

As suggested in the comment by yanys, you can interrogate a [`ZoneId`](//docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) for a particular `ZoneOffset` by passing a moment as an `Instant`. The [`Instant`](//docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

This is just another route to the same destination. Just like with `OffsetDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime` discussed above, we are specifying (a) a time zone, and (b) a moment.

```
Instant instant = zdtXmas.toInstant();
ZoneOffset zo = z.getRules().getOffset( instant );
```

> For ZoneId: America/Montreal at instant: 2017-12-25T05:00:00Z the ZoneOffset is: -05:00

See all these examples’ [code live at IdeOne.com](//ideone.com/cROb1H).

### `ZoneOffset.systemDefault`

The `ZoneOffset` class, a subclass of `ZoneId`, inherits the [`systemDefault`](//docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#systemDefault()) method. However, we cannot use that method for the purpose of determining the current offset. The inherited method returns an object of the superclass, `ZoneId`, not an object of the subclass, `ZoneOffset`.

```
ZoneOffset zoneOffset = ZoneOffset.systemDefault() ;  // Error.
// Fails to compile. 
// Every ZoneOffset is a ZoneId, but not every ZoneId is a ZoneOffset. 
// We cannot assign a superclass object to a reference variable of the subclass type.
```

> error: incompatible types: ZoneId cannot be converted to ZoneOffset

But there is another way.

#### Rules of the time zone

To get the current offset, we must take an alternate route. We need to go through the rules of the default time zone.

```java
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault ( );
ZoneRules rules = zoneId.getRules ( );
```

The rules change over time — by definition, as discussed above. So we must specify the moment for which we want to know the offset in effect. We specify the moment as an `Instant` object, a date and time as seen with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC.

```java
Instant now = Instant.now ( );
ZoneOffset offset = rules.getOffset ( now );
```

Dump to console.

```java
System.out.println ( "For zone " + zoneId + " at " + now + ", the offset is " + offset );
```

> For zone America/Los_Angeles at 2023-07-07T23:19:09.084624Z, the offset is -07:00

## Solar Time versus Political time

A bit more about offsets and time zones…

[Solar Time](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_time) has been used since pre-history, tracking each day by noting when the sun is directly overhead. Poke a stick in the ground, and watch its shadow. When the shadow is shortest, when the shadow begins to grow rather than shrink, then you know it is now noon. Formalize that with a [sundial](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sundial) to track the hours pass.

With solar time, as you travel from town to town moving westward, noon arrives a little bit later. Moving eastward, noon arrives a bit sooner. So every town has its own noon, shared only with towns to the north and south along the same longitude.

Solar time was largely abandoned in the modern era. As trains, telegraphs, and telephones arrived, so did the need to coordinate temporally. So a point was picked for its near solar time of noon, and a large swath of land so many miles to the west and to the east is declared to all share the same 12:00 on the clock, the **same number of hours offset ahead or behind the [Greenwich Prime Meridian](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_meridian_(Greenwich)) line**. So began the tradition of every train stop displaying prominently a clock to let the town know of the [standard time](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_time) for their larger region rather than solar time for their own town. Generally, towns in the western edge of that time zone region will see their train station clock read 12:00 a little *before* the sun is overhead. Clocks in towns in the eastern edge of the region read 12:00 a little *after* the sun is overhead.

Politicians around the world showed a penchant for changing the offset(s) of their jurisdiction. The reasons vary, such diplomacy, war & occupation, and the silliness of [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time). The reasons vary, but their changes come with surprising frequency. A time zone is a name given to a region to track its history of such changes. So an **[offset-from-UTC](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds** ahead or behind the prime meridian. A **time zone is much more: a history** of the past, present, and future changes to the offsets of a particular region. While two neighboring regions may today share the same offset-from-UTC, in the past or future they may differ depending on the differing whims or logic of their politicians.

This means modern time-tracking defined by politicians has little to do with geography. For example, the huge country of India today has a single time zone (offset-from-UTC of +05:30). So solar noon (sun directly over your head) is hours apart in various places across the vast subcontinent. The politicians of India decided this to help unify their diverse democracy. In other examples around the world, we see regions use their time zone as a symbol for international relations such as being different than their offending neighbor country, or choosing the same zone as a neighbor as relations thaw as seen recently in North Korea changing to match South Korea. So, nowadays, solar time is only one of several considerations in time-tracking.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](//docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](//docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](//docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](//docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](//docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](//jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](//www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](//docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](//openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](//www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](//developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](//developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](//github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](//www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See "*[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project*%22).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

Comment: you mean value of offset is different at different times in a zone? thx a lot!

Comment: @FredSuvn That is the very definition of Daylight Saving Time (DST), half the year one offset and half the year another. And DST is not the only cause; other anomalies cause changes in offset for particular time zones. For example, in autumn 2016, [Turkey decided to permanently adjust their offset one hour](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/turkey-scraps-dst-2016.html) further ahead of UTC (`+03:00`). Politicians frequently make such changes, often with little notice. That leaves people scrambling to update their computers’ 'tzdata' database listing of zone definitions.

Comment: Best answer I've seen on SO in quite a while   @FredSuvn you should accept the answer by clicking the ✅

Comment: For anyone else who is confused by the equation *Time Zone = ( History-of-offsets + Rules-for-anomalies )*. This **does not** mean that when using `zone.getRules().getOffset(instant)`, you need to add any additional anomalies to the acquired offset manually, such as DST. **The offset returned by `getOffset(instant)` is already the exact number of hours, minutes and seconds offset from GMT at that *instant* in time.** (I always thought the offset is just the geographic offset which describes how much earlier/later the sun rises in that region, but it is actually considering all the rules.)

Comment: @anddero Your comment inspired me to delete that equation, and add a section about solar time versus political time. Hopefully that reads more clearly now.

Comment: I suspect that the reason my you can't compile with a ZoneOffset.systemDefault() call is that the return type is ZoneId (the parent class of ZoneOffset).

Comment: @user3347392 Yes, that makes sense. The method is directly inherited by ZoneOffset from ZoneId. Thanks, I have updated the Answer to make your point.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your objective, you may be able to **bypass `ZoneOffset` entirely**.

Assuming you just need a `ZoneOffset` for e.g. `LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond()`, you may replace

```
ZoneOffset offset = OffsetDateTime.now().getOffset();
LocalDateTime dt1 = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(seconds, 0, offset);
```

with

```
LocalDateTime dt2 = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(
    Instant.ofEpochSecond(seconds), 
    ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

where `dt1.equals(dt2)` is `true`.