# Add a Java 8 ISO 8601 time duration expression to java.util.Date

Tags: java, date, duration, java-time, iso8601

I have an expression like `"PT20.345S"`, `"P2DT3H4M"` etc as described here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-

How can I parse this, add it to the current time and get a `java.util.Date` object?

Neither works:

```
Date d1 = Date.from(LocalDateTime.now().plus(Duration.parse(_expression)));
Date d2 = Date.from(Duration.parse(_expression).addTo(LocalDateTime.now()));
```

Comment: FYI: (A) Try to avoid the `java.util.Date` class. Supplanted entirely by the `java.time.Instant` class years ago. (B) Never use `LocalDateTime` when you mean an actual moment, a specific point on the timeline. Use `Instant`, `ZonedDateTime`, or `OffsetDateTime`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Duration amountToAdd = Duration.parse("PT20.345S");  // Represent a span of time. Here, about twenty and a third seconds.
Instant now = Instant.now() ;                        // Capture the current moment in UTC.
Instant otherMoment = now.plus(amountToAdd);         // Add the span-of-time to the current moment, for a moment in the future (or in the past if the duration is negative).
String output = otherMoment.toString():              // Generate a String in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

> 2018-06-30T19:34:47Z

Convert from modern *java.time* class to legacy class.

```
Date date1 = Date.from(otherMoment);
System.out.println(date1);
```

Running just now in Europe/Copenhagen time zone I got:

> Sat Jun 30 21:34:47 CEST 2018

If I use your other example duration string, `P2DT3H4M`, I got:

> Tue Jul 03 00:38:26 CEST 2018

Or if you’re into one-liners:

```
    Date date1 = Date.from(Instant.now().plus(Duration.parse("PT20.345S")));
```

The `java.util.Date` class is long outdated, so ideally you shouldn’t want to have one. If you need one anyway, typically for a legacy API that you cannot change or don’t want to change just now, you are thinking correctly when doing as much of the logic as possible using `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, and converting to `Date` only in the end. `Date`’s closest cousin in the modern world is `Instant`, and direct conversions between `Instant` and `Date` exist, which is why I am using this class. An `Instant` is also lovely independent of zone offsets and time zones.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the first solution should work if you convert the `LocalDateTime` to `Instant` with `ZoneOffset` (example UTC, or default of your system using `ZoneOffset.systemDefault()`) like below:

```
Date d1 = Date.from(LocalDateTime.now().plus(Duration.parse(_expression)).toInstant(OffsetDateTime.now().getOffset());
```

**However**, `LocalDateTime` is wrongly used in this case, because it does not represent a moment, is not a point on the timeline

From [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html):

> This class does not store or represent a time-zone. Instead, it is a description of the date, as used for birthdays, combined with the local time as seen on a wall clock. It cannot represent an instant on the time-line without additional information such as an offset or time-zone.

But, an [Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is a moment on the timeline in UTC

> This class models a single instantaneous point on the time-line. This might be used to record event time-stamps in the application.

So, if you use an Instant, you know exactly what moment in time is being referred to, regardless of time zones. Since you are going to handle the business logic like adding amount of time to current time and convert to Date, this is a handy class to be used.

```
 Date date1 = Date.from(Instant.now().plus(Duration.parse("PT20.345S")));
```

Comment: Thank you! But why `ZoneOffset.systemDefault()` returns a ZoneId object? It's one of the reasons I am avoiding the new api...

Comment: The goal is to get the Date object plus the specified amount of time. If I use ZoneOffset.UTC, will I achieve it or I need to look how to get a ZoneOffset for the default time zone?

Comment: Firstly, sorry I didn't check `ZoneOffset.systemDefault()` return ZoneId instead. Then you may use `OffsetDateTime.now().getOffset()` to get the default system offset (Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41427384/how-to-get-default-zoneoffset-in-java8)

Comment: sorry to unmark your advice, the other answer is closer: just take Instant instead of LocalDateTime, and then "add" returns Instant as well, which happily converts to Date

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is exactly the wrong class to be using here. It does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. See the [correct Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51117942/642706) by Ole V.V.

Comment: It’s okay @fedd

Comment: Also thanks for your feedbacks @Basil, should I correct my answer and put an explaination why not to use ‘LocalDateTime’ in this case ?

Comment: @NguyenPhung Sure. The Answer by Ole V.V. pretty much has it covered. So I suggest either fixing yours and take your own stab at explanation and example code, or delete.

Comment: @fedd This: `OffsetDateTime.now().getOffset()` has the same effect as this: `ZoneOffset.systemDefault()`. I suggest the second: shorter and your intent is more obvious to the reader. FYI: An offset-from-UTC is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds, nothing more. A time zone is history of past, present, and future changes in the offset used by the people of a particular region. For example, most of the people in the west coast of North America, `America/Los_Angeles`, use an offset of `-08:00` (eight hours behind UTC) for half the year, and an offset of `-07:00` the other half of the year.