# How to get ZoneOffset from LocalDateTime

Tags: datetime, java-8

How to get `ZoneOffset` from `LocalDateTime`?

I need to convert `LocalDateTime` to `OffsetDateTime`. to do that i need `ZoneOffset` and i need to maintain accurate date and time

How to get `ZoneOffset` from that `LocalDateTime` object?

Comment: `LocalDateTime` doesn't have offset or zone information.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41427384/how-to-get-default-zoneoffset-in-java8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get default ZoneOffset in java8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41427384/how-to-get-default-zoneoffset-in-java8)